# auto close flash file in action script 2

Tags: flash, actionscript

In a flash animation when animation reached to particular frame the flash file should close automatically

Here i written the code which is not working in AS2

```
fscommand("quit"); on 250 keyframe.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `import flash.system.fscommand;
fscommand("quit");`